# How to find all limit points of this set?

Tags: analysis

How to find all limit points of this set?

$S=\left\{\frac{x}{y} \mid x, y\in  ℕ  , x \leq y\right\}$ also $S \subset ℝ$.

Is the way to proof this done same way as it is for sequences? I have never done it for sets before that's why I'm wondering.

Comment: To get the math to render you need to include it beyween dollars like `$x\le y $` to get $x\le y $; note that `$\mathbb{N}$` can  be used to get $\mathbb{N}$ too.

Comment: Thank you for saying! I have tried to find it out myself but failed. Well at least I learned what latex is and how I can write like that correctly now. :)

Comment: 0 <x <=y means 0 < x/y <= 1.   So S = (0,1] intersect Q.  Q is dense in R so any real number in [0,1] is a limit point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you can see that the limit points of the set is the real interval $[0, 1]$.

To show that, for any given $a \in [0, 1]$ we find a sequence $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), \ldots$ that converges to $a$.

As a real number, $a$ has a decimal expansion: 
$$ a = 0,a_1 a_2 \ldots $$
Now, by picking, for example:
$$ (x_1, y_1) = (a_1, 10) \\
(x_2, y_2) = (10a_1 + a_2, 100) \\
\cdots $$

We obtain a succession of points in $S$ that converges to $a$, for any $a \in [0, 1)$.

The case $a = 1$ is rather trivial.